# how can i sum first n items in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

example

```
a = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1 ,0]]
result = [[a[0,0], a[0,0]+a[0,1], a[0,0]+a[0,1]+a[0,2], a[0,0]+a[0,1]+a[0,2]+a[0,3]], [a[1,0], a[1,0]+a[1,1], a[1,0]+a[1,1]+a[1,2], a[1,0]+a[1,1]+a[1,2]+a[1,3]]
       = [[1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2 ,2]]
```

I don't known how to do this, please help me. thx

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lookink for the cumulative sum, [`tf.cumsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/cumsum), along the second axis:

```
a = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1 ,0]])
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# run the graph and calculate the cumsum
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    print (sess.run(tf.cumsum(a, axis=1)))):

[[1 1 2 2]
 [0 1 2 2]]
```

Comment: I didn't know about this API before. Thank you so much!